# Trying to append new objects under alphabetic arranged "div" list

Tags: javascript, html

so I have an empty array, as the user, you can add new objects to the array. In the html file I have a list of div's sorted alphabetically. I want that every new object the user creates will be append under the div with the innerHTML that is equal to the first letter of the "name" property in the new object the user created.
I can't find an algorithm for that, can some one help make this work?

There is the HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script async src="music.app.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="music.app.css">
    <title>music app</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <div>Songs</div>
        <div>Playing</div>
        <div>Playlist</div>
    </nav>
 <div class="add-sort-continer">   
    <div class="sort-nav">=
     <ul>
        <li>Name</li>
        <li>Artist</li>
        <li>Alboms</li>
     </ul>
    </div>
    <button class="add-song">+</button>
 </div>
 <div class="sort-continer">
<div class="sort-name-continer">A</div>
<div class="sort-name-continer">B</div>
<div class="sort-name-continer">C</div>
<div class="sort-name-continer">D</div>
<div class="sort-name-continer">E</div>
<div class="sort-name-continer">F</div>
<div class="sort-name-continer">G</div>
<div class="sort-name-continer">H</div>
<div class="sort-name-continer">I</div>
<div class="sort-name-continer">J</div>
<div class="sort-name-continer">K</div>
<div class="sort-name-continer">L</div>
<div class="sort-name-continer">M</div>
<div class="sort-name-continer">N</div>
<div class="sort-name-continer">O</div>
<div class="sort-name-continer">P</div>
<div class="sort-name-continer">Q</div>
<div class="sort-name-continer">R</div>
<div class="sort-name-continer">S</div>
<div class="sort-name-continer">T</div>
<div class="sort-name-continer">U</div>
<div class="sort-name-continer">V</div>
<div class="sort-name-continer">W</div>
<div class="sort-name-continer">X</div>
<div class="sort-name-continer">Y</div>
<div class="sort-name-continer">Z</div>
<div class="sort-name-continer">@</div>
</div>

<div class="add-song-continer" id="add-song-continer">
    <form id="add-song-form">
      <button class="close-btn" id="close-add-song">X</button>
      <h1 class="h1-add-Song" >Add your song baby</h1>
      <br>
      <input type="text" class="song-name-add" placeholder="Song Name" value=""><br>
      <br>
      <input type="text" class="artist-name-add" placeholder="Artist Name"><br>
      <br>
      <input type="text" class="albom-name-add" placeholder="Albom Name"><br>
      <br>
      <input type="text" class="mp3-file-add" placeholder="Song File"><br>
      <br>
      <input type="text" class="img-add" placeholder="Image"><br>
      <button class="add-song-btn" id = "add-song-btn"> Add Song</button>
    </form>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

and this is the JavaScript
I must to warn you the js file isn't well organized.
In addition i tried to take the other properties from the new object the user created and insert them in the new div as innerHTML, but you can ignore this  if you like.

```js
let songs = [];

const AddSongFunction = (ev) => {
  ev.preventDefault();

   let song = { 
      name: document.querySelector(".song-name-add").value, 
      artist: document.querySelector(".artist-name-add").value,
      albom: document.querySelector(".albom-name-add").value,
      fill: document.querySelector(".mp3-file-add").value,
      img: document.querySelector(".img-add").value
      };
      
  songs.push(song);
  document.querySelector("form").reset();

    console.log(songs);
    }
   

  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    document.getElementById("add-song-btn").addEventListener("click", AddSongFunction )
    
  });

for(let i = 0; i > songs.length; ++i){
  appendNewSongToList = () => {
    let newSongDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newSongDiv.className.add("song-continer");
    newSongDiv.innerHTML = `<img class='songImg' url=${this.img}>
    <div class="song-info"> ${this.name}  ${this.artist}  ${this.albom}</div>`;

    if (document.querySelector(".sort-name-continer").innerHTML == this.name.index){
      let sortByName;
      sortByName = document.querySelector(".sort-name-continer");  
  }else{
    defaultSortName = document.querySelector(".sort-name-continer").innerHTML('@');
    sortByName = defaultSortName
  };
  sortByName.appendChild(newSongDiv);
  }; 
  appendNewSongToList();
};
```

Any way i'm very open to new suggestion for improving overall and i'm open to criticism as well, thank you so much in advance

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 2):

If you can find a way to add extra data on your sort label `DIV`s (like a `data-attribute`) this will be easily done through the following solution.

Please consider how I modified the HTML part of the code. I added a `data-attr` called `sortletter` and passed in exactly the letter you are using in the div content. Like so:

```
<div class="sort-name-continer" data-sortletter="A">A</div>
```

and later on I used this attribute to select proper element:

```
document.querySelector(`[data-sortletter="A"]`)
```

Please check out the example below:

```js
function handleAddSongBtn(){
  const songObj = {
    name: .value, 
    artist: document.querySelector(".artist-name-add").value,
    album: document.querySelector(".album-name-add").value,
    fill: document.querySelector(".mp3-file-add").value,
    img: document.querySelector(".img-add").value
  }
  
  /** 
  * Here is where you select the proper sort label DIV by
  * using `data-sortletter` attribute on the DIVs
  * and first letter of new song's name property
  */
  const sortLabelBox = document.querySelector(`[data-sortletter="${songObj.name.charAt(0)}"]`)
  
  // If any sort label with the given letter exists
  if(sortLabelBox){
    // Then add a new DIV after the sort label DIV
    
    const newSongDiv = document.createElement('div')
    // You can add proper data from song object to this new DIV
    
    // Then do as follow to add this div after the sort label
    sortLabelBox.parentNode.insertAfter(newSongDiv, sortLabelBox)
  }
}

document.addEventListener('click', handleAddSongBtn)
```

```html
<div class="sort-continer">
  <div class="sort-name-continer" data-sortletter="A">A</div>
  <div class="sort-name-continer" data-sortletter="B">B</div>
  <div class="sort-name-continer" data-sortletter="C">C</div>
  <div class="sort-name-continer" data-sortletter="D">D</div>
</div>
  
<button class="add-song-btn" id = "add-song-btn">Add Song</button>
```

**Alternative solution:**
*In case if you can't modify your HTML code to add `data-attributes`*

If you can't have those `data-attribute`s you might need to do a loop to find the proper label DIV. In you JavaScript code, instead of query selecting the DIV by `data-attr`, do as follow:

```
const sortLabelBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('.sort-name-continer')
let properSortLabelBox;

for(let i = 0; i < sortLabelBoxes.length; i++){
    // if innerHTML equals first letter of the new song
    if(sortLabelBoxes[i].innerHTML === songObj.name.charAt(0)){
       properSortLabelBox = sortLabelBoxes[i]
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi first thank you for you time, this is the code i wrote `code` const sortLabelBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('.sort-name-continer')
let properSortLabelBox;

for(let i = 0; i < sortLabelBoxes.length; i++){
    // if innerHTML equals first letter of the new song
    if(sortLabelBoxes[i].innerHTML === songObj.name.charAt(0)){
       properSortLabelBox = sortLabelBoxes[i]
    }
} if I have any mistakes I will be happy to know, in addition where do I put the code in my original code?  because I wasn't able to make the code work for me.